# Wix - Run Batch File on Uninstall

Tags: wix, installation, uninstallation

So This CustomAction already work only for RunBatch ID, Running When Before Finalize Install. But It didn't work for uninstall, did i miss something ?

```
<CustomAction Id="RunBatch" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]Tester.bat" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncWait" />
<CustomAction Id="Uninstall" ExeCommand="[INSTALLFOLDER]Tester.bat"  Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RunBatch" Before="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Uninstall" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When I Run Uninstall from Installer or even control panel, batch file still not running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Fix It After Change

```
<Custom Action="Uninstall" Before="RemoveFiles">Installed</Custom>
```

to

```
<Custom Action="Uninstall" After="InstallInitialize">(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE="ALL")</Custom>
```